# Modify CSS of object without an ID to reference

Tags: javascript

Can I reference an HTML element without an ID?

```js
function doThis(id) {
 document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<button id="removeThisId" onclick="doThis(this.id)">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: You can select it in million different ways: A classname, its position in the DOM, its attributes and their values, ...

Comment: What is the actual application?

Comment: If no id exists, you add one. Or, you use some other ways to identify it, like a style class. But the best way is to just add an id, because it'd be stupidly easy to mess things up otherwise.

Comment: if you send the reference to the object this way then you don't need to `getElementById`. Just `<button onclick="doThis(this)">Click Me</button>` and `function doThis(elem) {
 elem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}`

Comment: What is your opposition to an id?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Thanks, that's what I was after!

Answer (score 1):

You can query the DOM's elements with a variety of Javascript functions, the most general being `querySelector()`.

`querySelector()` accepts any CSS selector ratified after [Selectors API Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall), allowing you to reference elements by [their `.class`, `tag` or `[attributes=value]` and more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

For example, to query for the `button` element you described *without* using it's ID, you could write the following:

```
var el = document.body.querySelector('button[onclick="doThis(this.id)"]')
```